# Get Azure VM size inside on a windows machine

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I do only have access on a Windows VM which is hosted on Azure.

Is there a way to find out the VM size inside of the virtual machine, lets say for example over commandline (powershell / cmd), without having further information about the envrionment like for example Ressource Group or VM Ressource Name?

I did find a way like this, but it requires the information about the name of VM and Ressource group:

```
$VM = Get-AzureRMVM –Name HSG-Linux1 –ResourceGroupName HSG-AzureRG
$VM.HardwareProfile
```

[Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/retrieve-azure-resource-manager-virtual-machine-properties-by-using-powershell-part-2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the metada to get the VM information inside the VM like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2019-03-11 -Method get
```

For more details, see [Azure Instance Metadata service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service). You can also put the output as a variable, then get the special properties. For example:

```
$vm = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2019-03-11 -Method get
$vm.vmSize
```

Or get the property directly through the request like this:

```
$vmSize = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/vmSize?api-version=2019-03-11&&format=text" -Method get
```

Comment: Great, I was searching for this command for hours. Thanks a million Charles Xu. By the way, `$vm.compute.resourceGroupName` didn't work for me, but  for that `$vm.vmSize` works great.

Comment: @EmbaBakar It's just an example as I said. You can get the info as you want. Then if it works for you, you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Cool, you did change your answer to `$vm.vmSize` which is a working well example. Now I can accept the answer. Good cooperation.

Comment: @EmbaBakar What is the reason that you unmark the answer?

Comment: Why did you edit your correct example again to a not working example? Is the following command working on your env: `$vm.compute.vmSize` ? In my env. it doesn't give an output, the correct way to get an output is `$vm.vmSize`.

Comment: @EmbaBakar I update the answer with the wrong action. It's my mistake. You can check the update. Maybe it's more suitable for you.